# How to get dragshadow visible

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, onlongclicklistener

So I'm using longclicklistener and on longclick I want to start dragging. This works really good but there is some special case when I want to add first another view on layout and then start dragging with added view.

When I'm doing that everything else is working well but the dragshadow won't be Visible. I'm using custom shadowbuilder but it's just normal with scaling view and I have tried it with normal shadowbuilder also. Dragging is working as it should but just shadow won't show up. My code look like this:

```
View.OnLongClickListener longlistener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        ...
        LinearLayout another = copy(v); //making copy of view
        //doing some changes on it
        ((LinearLayout) v.getParent()).addView(another); //adding it on parent

        //starting drag like normal
        ClipData clipdata = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowbuilder = new MyDragShadowBuilder(another);
        v.startDrag(clipdata, shadowbuilder, another, 0);


        return true;
    }
};
```

I have also tried this

```
another.startDrag(clipdata, shadowbuilder, another, 0);
```